# OnGet Handler Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am using ASP .Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages (non-MVC).

I have a model that looks like this:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

My OnGet Handler looks like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    Person = await _db.Person.ToListAsync();
    return Page();
}
```

I would like to sort the results of the OnGet Handler by LastName.

**Additional information:**

Implemented the fix below.

Now getting the following error:

Getting error CS1061 on the .OrderBy

'List' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no accessible extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public IList<Person> Person { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    var result = await _db.Person.ToListAsync();
    Person = result.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
    return Page(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
Person = await _db.Person.OrderBy(x => x.LastName).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
    var result = await _db.Person.ToListAsync();
    Person = result.OrderBy(x => x.LastName);
    return Page(); 
}
```